# Issue with huge listview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

OK, here's the issue :

I'm building a simple dictionary app (going to be a PhoneGap/Cordova-based native iOS app) using jQuery Mobile.

The thing is I'm using a `listview` component which is supposed to be able to handle **lots** of items (some tens of thousands).

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="false" data-autodividers='true' data-filter-placeholder="Search here...">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    ...
</ul>
```

As you've probably guessed, it's SLOW : it takes **too much** time to load, scrolling is simply **horrible**, not to mention filtering (a.k.a. as-you-type).

*The amount of data that the listview seems to be able to handle properly (at least when tested on a browser) is somewhere between 1000 and 2000 entries - which is still far from enough.*

So, what would you suggest? Any ideas on how to make this work?

---

**P.S.** Note that I'm not such a jQuery Mobile guru. I'm just experimenting with it, to see whether (if at all) it could be speed up the development of some types of iOS apps (while making them portable to other mobile platforms as well). Well, yes, it seems I've stumbled upon the first real issue... lol

Comment: Can you load the first `X` number on page load and then run subsequent `AJAX` requests to retrieve the next `Y` number? If all values are **required**, you could add a loading icon while the `AJAX` requests are still going out.

Comment: @Aiias That's the only thing that has come to my mind so far. I've also had a look at the LazyLoader plugin (http://dcarrith.github.io/jquery.mobile.lazyloader/), although I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

Comment: I agree with both comments. You should definitely follow a lazy loading strategy and show only what is needed. In my opinion, in each Ajax request you should remove the other list items from DOM and add only the list items retrieved through this Ajax request. This way will prevent the existence of thousands list items in DOM which results in memory issues and slow performance.